# Python: Creating a month() function to take 1 - 12 as input and return corresponding month

Tags: python, string, function, operations

I am currently trying to create a month() function that will take the numbers 1 through 12 as input and return the three character abbreviation of the corresponding month. I need to do this without the use of an if statement, and using string operations. I must also use a single string to store all of the abbreviations. I am currently stumped on this function to the point where I can't even think of a way to begin it, just seems to be one of those simple problems that are complex for me.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what other restrictions there are, but split is a string operation. So, something like this should work:

split, will turn the string in to a list, and then you simply return the value corresponding to the index you provide. The "-1" is because lists always start at index 0.

```
def month(n):
    a = "Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec".split()
    return a[n - 1]
```

Demo:

month(4) -> Apr

Without the restrictions, the ideal approach to convert a number to the three letter month abbreviation would be to use Python's datetime as such:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('4', '%m').strftime('%b')
```

The above will output 'Apr'

Comment: isn't a inizializad array more efficient?

Comment: @beppe9000 The OP requirements were to store everything in a string first. Ideally if you want to do a lookup like this you should use a dictionary. Furthermore, for dates, you can very easily use datetime to get what you want as well. Using datetime you can very easily do this: `datetime.strptime('3', '%m').strftime('%b')`. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: whoops i overlooked that part :)

Answer (score 0):

A slice operation allows you to return a piece of a larger string.

```
>>> 'abcde'[2:4]
'cd'
>>> 'fghijkl'[2:2+3]
'hij'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def month(num):
    month = 'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec'
    print month[(num-1)*3:num*3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def month(n):
    end = 3*n - 1
    start = end - 2
    return 'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec'[start:end+1]

for i in range(1,13):
    print(month(i))

Jan
Feb
Mar
Apr
May
Jun
Jul
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another variation:

```
>>> for m in range(1, 13):
        print 'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec'[:3*m][-3:],

Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

And another:

```
>>> for m in range(1, 13):
        print ' JFMAMJJASONDaeapauuuecoenbrrynlgptvc'[m::12],

Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
```